# multiple findAll in one for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeatufulSoap to read some data from web page.
This code works fine, but I would like to improve it.

How do I make the `for` loop to extract more than one piece of data per iteration? Here I have 3 `for` loops to get values from:

```
for elem in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="grad"): ...
for elem in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="ulica"): ...
for elem in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="kada"): ...
```

How to change this to work in one `for` loop? Of course I'd like a simple solution.
Output can be list

My code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get data from a web page into the ``html`` varaible here

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'lxml')

mj=[]
adr=[]
vri=[]

for mjesto in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="grad"):
    print (mjesto.get_text())
    mj.append(mjesto.get_text())


for adresa in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="ulica"):
    print (adresa.get_text())
    adr.append(adresa.get_text())


for vrijeme in bsObj.findAll('div', class_="kada"):
    print (vrijeme.get_text())
    vri.append(vrijeme.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup's `select` method to target your various desired elements, and do whatever you want with them.  In this case we are going to simplify the CSS selector pattern by using the `:is()` pseudo-class, but basically we are searching for any `div` that has class `grad`, `ulica`, or `kada`. As each element is returned that matches the pattern, we just sort them by which class they correspond to:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

lokacija="http://www.hep.hr/ods/bez-struje/19?dp=koprivnica&el=124"
datum="12.02.2019"
lokacija=lokacija+"&datum="+datum
print(lokacija)
r = requests.get(lokacija)
print(type(str(r)))
print(r.status_code)

html = urlopen(lokacija)

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'lxml')

print("Datum radova:",datum)
print("HEP područje:",bsObj.h3.get_text())

mj=[]
adr=[]
vri=[]
hep_podrucje=bsObj.h3.get_text()

for el in bsObj.select('div:is(.grad, .ulica, .kada)'):
    if 'grad' in el.get('class'):
        print (el.get_text())
        mj.append(el.get_text())
    elif 'ulica' in el.get('class'):
        print(el.get_text())
        adr.append(el.get_text())
    elif 'kada' in el.get('class'):
        print (el.get_text())
        vri.append(el.get_text())
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this requires BeautifulSoup 4.7+.

Comment: how to put all this to string that can be send with email ?? this example is only for one location, there is 87 in total...so I have for loop that extract locations, time and address where are operations on power lines... Now this example for all 87 locations works fine, but how to put in string file ?

Comment: I wasn't really sure what you wanted to do with the data, but if you want one big string, you can simply join the results together as one string `"\n".join(mj + adr + vri)`. You also don't have to store them in separate variables, I just wasn't sure what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Note: basic explanation ahead. If you know this, skip directly to the listing of possibilities

To change the code into a loop, you have to look at the part that stays the same and the part that varies. In your case, you find a `div`, get the text and append it to a list.

The `class` attribute of the `div` objects varies each time, so does the list you append to. A `for` loop works by having one variable that is assigned different values each iteration, then executig the code within.

We get a basic structure:

```
for div_class in <div classes>:
    <stuff to do>
```

Now, in `<stuff to do>`, we have a different list each time. We need some way of getting a different list into the loop. For this, there are multiple possibilities:

- Put the list into a `dict` and use item lookup
- `zip` the lists with `<div classes>` and iterate over them

The first two will involve using nested loops, the result looking similar to this:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
for div_class, the_list in zip(['div_cls1', 'div_cls2', 'div_cls3'], [list_1, list_2, list_3]):
    for elem in bsObj.find_all('div', class_=div_class):
        the_list.append(elem.get_text())
```

or

```
lists = {'div_cls1': [], 'div_cls2': [], 'div_cls3': []}
for div_class in lists:  # note: keys MUST match the class of div elements
    for elem in bsObj.find_all('div', class_=div_class):
        lists[div_class].append(elem.get_text)
```

Of course, the inner loop could be replaced by list comprehension (works for the `dict` approach): `lists[div_class] = [elem.get_text() for elem in bsObj.find_all('div', class_=div_class)]`